# why can't I override a method that returns some View?

Tags: swift, swiftui, overriding

In the following example

```
import SwiftUI

class AbstractOverride {
    open func configurationView() -> AnyView {
        if Features.TEST_VERSION {
            return AnyView(Text("override configurationView()"))
        } else {
            return AnyView(EmptyView())
        }
    }
    
    open func someConfigurationView() -> some View {
        if Features.TEST_VERSION {
            return AnyView(Text("override someConfigurationView()"))
        } else {
            return AnyView(EmptyView())
        }
    }

}

class SubclassOverride: AbstractOverride {
    override func configurationView() -> AnyView { // no compiler error
        return AnyView(Text("Test"))
    }

    override func someConfigurationView() -> some View { // compiler error "Method does not override any method from its superclass"
        return AnyView(Text("Test"))
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error `compiler error "Method does not override any method from its superclass"` at `override func someConfigurationView() -> some View`.

There is no compiler error returning `AnyView`.

can anybody explain what is happening here? Why does Swift not recognise that the method signatures are the same?

This is iOS 13, Xcode 11.5

Comment: Well, from interface perspective `some View` means `Unknown`, and as any unknown `Unknown != Unknown`. Whereas `AnyView` is known, so `AnyView == AnyView`, so method signatures are equal and method can be overridden.

Comment: @Uilleann, workaround is in a question - use `AnyView`

Comment: I don't see why this isn't already a compiler feature. It already knows the concrete type of `some View` in `AbstractOverride`...

Answer (score 4):

The language design has dictated that it is completely impossible for the programmer to ***statically*** be provided with information about the relationship of two opaque types, such as whether they exist in a class inheritance chain.

```swift
var instanceOfType1: some ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral = true

var anotherInstanceOfType1 = instanceOfType1 as! Bool // "fine" 

// Cannot assign value of type 'some ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral' to type 'Bool'
anotherInstanceOfType1 = instanceOfType1

var instanceOfType2: some ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral = instanceOfType1 // fine
type(of: instanceOfType1) == type(of: instanceOfType2) // true

// Cannot assign value of type 'some ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral' (type of 'instanceOfType1')
// to type 'some ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral' (type of 'instanceOfType2')
instanceOfType2 = instanceOfType1
```

[Originally, using opaque types in non-final declarations was forbidden.](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0244-opaque-result-types.md#restrictions-on-opaque-result-types)

> opaque result types cannot be used for a non-final declaration within
> a class…

> This restriction could conceivably be lifted in the future, but it would
> mean that override implementations would be constrained to returning
> the same type as their super implementation, meaning they must call
> super.method() to produce a valid return value.

The restriction has been lifted, but it is currently impossible to make use of it. E.g. even the simplest possible override will not compile.

```swift
override func someConfigurationView() -> some View {
  super.someConfigurationView()
}
```

Opaque types can provide no protection against breaking the ['L'-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). `some View` may actually be the same or a subtype of `some View` (as your `AnyViews` are), but there's no way for the language to enforce that.

…for example, that contract-breaking happens if you write without `AnyView`, as you should be be doing:

```swift
class AbstractOverride {
  @ViewBuilder func someConfigurationView() -> some View {
    if Features.TEST_VERSION {
      Text("override someConfigurationView()")
    }
  }
}

final class SubclassOverride {
  func someConfigurationView() -> some View {
    Text("Test")
  }
}
```

The least painful solution is to just completely disallow yourself from using class inheritance in Swift. It has never been idiomatic—it's really only there for interaction with Objective-C.

```swift
struct ContentView<
  ConfigurationViewProvider: ModuleName.ConfigurationViewProvider
>: View {
  var body: some View {
    ConfigurationViewProvider.someConfigurationView
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView<SubclassOverride>()
  }
}
```

```swift
protocol ConfigurationViewProvider {
  associatedtype ConfigurationView: View

  @ViewBuilder static var someConfigurationView: ConfigurationView { get }
}

enum AbstractOverride: ConfigurationViewProvider {
  static var someConfigurationView: some View {
    if Features.TEST_VERSION {
      Text("override someConfigurationView()")
    }
  }
}

enum SubclassOverride: ConfigurationViewProvider {
  static var someConfigurationView: some View {
    Text("Test")
  }
}
```